# Trigger jQuery's .on() event when page loads

Tags: jquery

I need jQuery's .on() event to fire when the page has loaded. I have some dynamically generated checkboxes based on the users selections on the previous screen. I have code that does what I want it to but i've bound it to the 'body' click event to allow me to test it works.

What I have is the following and need this to trigger as soon as the page loads instead of the body click.

```
$('body').on('click', function (e) {
    $("input:checkbox").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("disabled") == "disabled") {
            $(this).parent().addClass('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities for you:

1) Just put your script tag containing your code at the very end of the page, just before the closing `</body>` tag, and remove it from within an event handler:

```
<script>
$("input:checkbox").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr("disabled") == "disabled") {
        $(this).parent().addClass('disabled');
    }
});
</script>
</body>
```

All of the checkboxes defined *above* the code in the HTML will be available at that point, references:

- [YUI Best Practices for Speeding Up your Website](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html)
- [Google on when DOM elements are ready](http://groups.google.com/group/closure-library-discuss/browse_thread/thread/1beecbb5d6afcb41)

---

2) Alternately, if you have some reason to put the script tag elsewhere, you can use [jQuery's `ready` event](http://api.jquery.com/ready), which fires after the page is ready but before `onload` (usually):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("input:checkbox").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("disabled") == "disabled") {
            $(this).parent().addClass('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, both these dont work for me. I'm already doing it in the document ready but as the inputs are created dynamiclly using jQuery the DOM is not seeing them unless I use .on() when I can get access but need an event to trigger such as click, focus.

Comment: @KDee: If you're adding them dynamically, just run the relevant code after adding them. For instance, once you've created a new one, and assuming you have a jQuery wrapper for it called `newItem` that refers to the element containing the checkbox: `if (newItem.find("input:checkbox[disabled=disabled]")[0]) { newItem.addClass("disabled"); }` which says "If there are any disabled checkboxes within `newItem`, add the `"disabled"` class to `newItem`.

Comment: I'll accept your answer as it has helped solve my problem by assigning the classes at the point of dynamic generation. It would be good to still find out if what I asked is possible. I'll keep exploring and will post a solution if I find anything.

Comment: @KDee: What you asked was how to do this on page load, which I answered. There's no other event fired (not a current cross-browser one) when you add content to the document, that's why **you** have to trigger the code as part of adding the element. The next version of the DOM may have [mutation observers](http://www.w3.org/TR/domcore/#mutationobserver), which would let you trigger your code upon modification of a container element, but while some browsers have support, you can't use it in general web stuff yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("input:checkbox").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("disabled") == "disabled") {
            $(this).parent().addClass('disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

The document.ready handler makes the function activate when the page is done loading.

Comment: I did have it in the document.ready, but that has no effect as the controls are generated dynamically. Using .on allows me to access these controls but i need an event to trigger this.

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
// Here your .on handler codes
});